# AWS and CloudFormation: How to attach a Virtual Private Gateway to a Routing Table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to attach a Virtual Private Gateway to a Routing Table with CloudFormation

The following is the Route table JSON I have...

```
 "PrivateRouteTable": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::RouteTable",
            "Properties": {
                "VpcId": {
                    "Ref": "VPC"
                },
                "Tags": [{
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "Private_RouteTable-AZ-A"
                }]
            }
        },
        "DefaultPrivateRoute": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Route",
            "Properties": {
                "RouteTableId": {
                    "Ref": "PrivateRouteTable"
                },
                "DestinationCidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0",
                "NatGatewayId": {
                    "Ref": "NatGateway"
                }
            }
        },
        "PrivateSubnetRouteTableAssociation": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation",
            "Properties": {
                "RouteTableId": {
                    "Ref": "PrivateRouteTable"
                },
                "SubnetId": {
                    "Ref": "PrivateSN"
                }
            }
        }
```

And this is the Virtual Private Gateway JSON I have..

```
"VirtualPrivateGateway": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPNGateway",
            "Properties": {
                "Type": "ipsec.1",
                "Tags": [{
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "Virtual Private Gateway"
                }]
            }
        },
        "AttachmentVPNGateway": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment",
            "Properties": {
                "VpcId": {
                    "Ref": "VPC"
                },
                "VpnGatewayId": {
                    "Ref": "VirtualPrivateGateway"
                }
            }
        },
        "VPNConnection": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPNConnection",
            "Properties": {
                "Type": "ipsec.1",
                "CustomerGatewayId": {
                    "Ref": "CustomerGateway"
                },
                "StaticRoutesOnly": true,
                "Tags": [{
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "VPN_Connection"
                }],
                "VpnGatewayId": {
                    "Ref": "VirtualPrivateGateway"
                }
            }
        }
```

There's more as well that creates the VPC, Subnet, etc, but I've left it out for simplicity sake.
The error happens if I try attach the VPG to the Route table with the following JSON...

```
        "VPGPrivateRoute": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Route",
            "Properties": {
                "RouteTableId": {
                    "Ref": "PrivateRouteTable"
                },
                "DestinationCidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0",
                "GatewayId": {
                    "Ref": "VirtualPrivateGateway"
                }
            }
        }
```

The error I receive from CloudFormation...

```
The gateway ID 'vgw-xxxxxxxxxxx' does not exist (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidGatewayID.NotFound; Request ID: e29700b2-2d76-4e19-9d13-b6f84e22b01c)
```

The documentation does say that I should be use "GatewayId" to associate a VPG to a route table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there should be [DependsOn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html) on the route table:

> A VPN gateway route propagation **depends** on a VPC-gateway attachment when you have a VPN gateway.

Maybe the following will help:

```
    "VPGPrivateRoute": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::Route",
        "DependsOn" : "AttachmentVPNGateway",
        "Properties": {
            "RouteTableId": {
                "Ref": "PrivateRouteTable"
            },
            "DestinationCidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0",
            "GatewayId": {
                "Ref": "VirtualPrivateGateway"
            }
        }
    }
```